# MySQL: Why would a query run faster with literal conditions compared to variables

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures

Not sure whether the actually query matters but, I have a MySQL Stored Procedure where I commented out the other parts of the proc except the following query...

```
INSERT INTO temp_attribution (`attribute_type`, `domain`, `id`, `name`, `score`, `rank`, `partner_match`, `person_match`, `sponsor_match`, `date_match`)
SELECT 'Campaign' AS attribute_type, domain, id, name, score, (@proc_counter := @proc_counter + 1) AS rank,
    partner_match, person_match, sponsor_match, date_match
FROM (
    SELECT m_c.domain, m_c.campaign_id AS id, m_c.name, m_c.client_id, m_c.sent_date,
        proc_sponsors AS invoice_sponsor, bs.sponsor AS campaign_sponsor, 
        proc_email AS invoice_email, aes_decrypt(m_r.email, in_encrypt_key) as campaign_email,
        if (m_c.client_id = proc_client_id COLLATE latin1_general_ci, 'Yes', 'No') AS partner_match,
        if (aes_encrypt(proc_email, in_encrypt_key) = m_r.email, 'Exact Email', 'Email Domain') AS person_match,
        if (LOCATE(CONVERT(bs.sponsor USING utf8mb4), proc_sponsors) > 0, 'Sponsor',
            if (CONVERT(bs.vendor USING utf8mb4) = proc_vendor, 'Vendor', 'No') )  AS sponsor_match,
        if (datediff(proc_invoice_date, m_c.sent_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 92, 'Within Three', 'Within Six') AS date_match,
        (
            if (m_c.client_id = proc_client_id COLLATE latin1_general_ci, 45, 10) + 30 +
            if (LOCATE(CONVERT(bs.sponsor USING utf8mb4), proc_sponsors) > 0, 10,
                if (CONVERT(bs.vendor USING utf8mb4) = proc_vendor, 5, 0) ) +
            if (datediff(proc_invoice_date, m_c.sent_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 92, 15, 5)
        ) AS score 
    FROM campaign_table m_c
    INNER JOIN recipient_table m_r ON m_c.domain = m_r.domain AND m_c.campaign_id = m_r.campaign_id
    LEFT JOIN booking_sponsor bs ON m_c.domain = bs.domain AND m_c.campaign_id = bs.campaign_id
    WHERE datediff(proc_invoice_date, m_c.sent_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 185
    AND ( aes_encrypt(proc_email, in_encrypt_key) = m_r.email OR m_r.email_domain = proc_email_domain )
) T ORDER BY score DESC, sent_date DESC LIMIT 5;
```

The fields starting with 'proc_' are actually variables declared at the beginning of the procedure and this only takes 0.385 seconds to initialise whereas the entire proc takes 15 seconds.

On a separate query window, I copied the relevant query and substituted variables starting with 'proc_' to test speed and optimise, like so...

```
INSERT INTO temp_attribution (`attribute_type`, `domain`, `id`, `name`, `score`, `rank`, `partner_match`, `person_match`, `sponsor_match`, `date_match`)
SELECT 'Campaign' AS attribute_type, domain, id, name, score, (@proc_counter := @proc_counter + 1) AS rank,
    partner_match, person_match, sponsor_match, date_match
FROM (
    SELECT m_c.domain, m_c.campaign_id AS id, m_c.name, m_c.client_id, m_c.sent_date,
        'VENDOR SPONSOR VALUE' AS invoice_sponsor, bs.sponsor AS campaign_sponsor, 
        'johnsmith@domain.com' AS invoice_email, aes_encrypt('johnsmith@domain.com', 'secret_key') as campaign_email,
        if (m_c.client_id = m_c.client_id COLLATE latin1_general_ci, 'Yes', 'No') AS partner_match,
        if (aes_encrypt('johnsmith@domain.com', 'secret_key'), 'Exact Email', 'Email Domain') AS person_match,
        if (LOCATE(CONVERT(bs.sponsor USING utf8mb4), 'VENDOR SPONSOR VALUE') > 0, 'Sponsor',
            if (CONVERT(bs.vendor USING utf8mb4) = 'VENDOR', 'Vendor', 'No') )  AS sponsor_match,
        if (datediff('2016-10-14', m_c.sent_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 92, 'Within Three', 'Within Six') AS date_match,
        (
            if (m_c.client_id = m_c.client_id COLLATE latin1_general_ci, 45, 10) + 30 +
            if (LOCATE(CONVERT(bs.sponsor USING utf8mb4), 'VENDOR SPONSOR VALUE') > 0, 10,
                if (CONVERT(bs.vendor USING utf8mb4) = 'VENDOR', 5, 0) ) +
            if (datediff('2016-10-14', m_c.sent_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 92, 15, 5)
        ) AS score
    FROM campaign_table m_c
    INNER JOIN recipient_table m_r ON m_c.domain = m_r.domain AND m_c.campaign_id = m_r.campaign_id
    LEFT JOIN booking_sponsor bs ON m_c.domain = bs.domain AND m_c.campaign_id = bs.campaign_id
    WHERE datediff('2016-10-14', m_c.sent_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 185
    AND ( aes_encrypt('johnsmith@domain.com', 'secret_key') = m_r.email OR m_r.email_domain = 'domain.com' )
) T ORDER BY score DESC, sent_date DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Now, magically without doing anything else, the query runs within two seconds. How is that possible?

Comment: proc_ are input parameters of stored procedure ?

Comment: If it was me, I think I'd try to reduce the problem to the minimal constituents necessary to cause the apparent bottleneck.

Comment: @PrabhatG 
Example: DECLARE proc_email_domain VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8mb4;
SET proc_email_domain = (SOME QUERY)

Comment: @Strawberry Even if I take just the inner most query and run it within a proc without any special calculation, it runs much slower inside the proc. Example: SELECT 1 FROM campaign_table m_c
    INNER JOIN recipient_table m_r ON m_c.domain = m_r.domain AND m_c.campaign_id = m_r.campaign_id
    LEFT JOIN booking_sponsor bs ON m_c.domain = bs.domain AND m_c.campaign_id = bs.campaign_id
    WHERE datediff('2016-10-14', m_c.sent_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 185
    AND ( aes_encrypt('johnsmith@domain.com', 'secret_key') = m_r.email OR m_r.email_domain = 'domain.com' )

Comment: @ShahidThaika : I am not sure enough, but it seems to be a `parameter sniffing` issue. You may read about it. Basically, store the `proc_email_domain` in a variable inside stored procedure, and use that variable everywhere else. Don't use input parameter directly inside stored procedure. This should do the trick.

Comment: @PrabhatG Excuse me if I was not clear, but the proc_email_domain and other proc_variables are all declared inside and not an input variable. Basically, these are parameters that don't change across their use in multiple queries within the entire procedure. So I calculate them once and re-use them.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Some of the declared variable type was different compared to the column being compared, so I guess MySQL could not compare them in the most efficient way possible.